# Repeat category name - PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

I created a database with 5 categories and created a page to display the available categories that I pull from the database. The problem is that I have 4 divs that have the following class ( col-md-3 ) and one that is ( col-md-6 ).

Code for gathering the first 5 categories ( col-md-3 ):

```
<?php 
    $this->db->limit(4); 
    $categories = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent' => 0))->result_array(); 
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category):
?>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <div class="grid-item-holder">
            <div class="listing-item-grid">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/category_thumbnails/').$category['thumbnail'];?>" alt="" />
                <div class="listing-counter">                        
                    <span>2</span>Locations
                </div>
                <div class="listing-item-cat">
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/filter_listings?category='.slugify($category['name']).'&&amenity=&&video=0&&status=all'); ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $category['name']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Code for gathering another 1 category ( col-md-6 ):

```
<?php 
    $this->db->limit(1); 
    $categories = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent' => 0))->result_array(); 
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category):
?>
    <div class="gallery-item gallery-item-second">
        <div class="grid-item-holder">
            <div class="listing-item-grid">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/category_thumbnails/').$category['thumbnail'];?>" alt="" />
                <div class="listing-counter">                        
                    <span>2</span>Locations
                </div>
                <div class="listing-item-cat">
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/filter_listings?category='.slugify($category['name']).'&&amenity=&&video=0&&status=all'); ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $category['name']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With this code, I get a display of categories but instead of displaying 5 categories, it repeats one of the displayed 4. How can I fix the code so that the display automatically continues to display the categories in all divs? If I forgot to write something, correct it or ask, I will update the question.

Comment: Are these code samples on the same page?  If so, why are you fetching "categories" twice?  Why not just fetch all of them and loop through everything that gets returned?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same page. Can you please give me an example or describe to me more what you mean? Thanks @David

Comment: Well, you're *explicitly querying* the first 4 records from the DB, then *explicitly querying* the first 1 record from the DB.  But why?  This seems like an excessive case of copying/pasting code that you got from somewhere without knowing what any of it does.  Why set `limit(4)` and `limit(1)` in these separate queries?  Why limit the results at all?  If the goal is to display all "categories" then remove any "limits" and just display all of the "categories" with one query and one loop.

Comment: I explain that in question. I have 5 divs, 4 divs have the same dimension and 1 is longer double. Understand? @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the first 4 items for the first foreach loop and then getting the first one again for the second loop. Would it make sense to get all 5 and process them in one single foreach loop only adding 'gallery-item-second' on the 5th item, something like ...

```
<?php 
    $this->db->limit(5); 
    $categories = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent' => 0))->result_array(); 
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category):
        $index++;
        if ($index == 5) {
            echo '<div class="gallery-item gallery-item-second">';
        } else {
           echo '<div class="gallery-item">';
        }
?>
        <div class="grid-item-holder">
        . . .
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or if you must have the second loop then get 5 items and only show the 5th.
And to make sure you get the same 5 you could use a sort criteria when you get the items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved with math:

I have added the next code:

```
...
$num = 5;
$i = 0;

foreach ($categories as $key => $category):
    if ($i < ($num - 1)) {
        // show div col-md-3
    } else {
        // show div col-md-6
    }
endif;
```